# How do you find a changeset on codeplex

Tags: git, codeplex

I've noticed in CodePlex, a changeset ID under the Source Control --> History section is shorter than the full changeset Id within the URL when viewing changeset.

How does one easily navigate to a changeset from the shorter ID, which is often quoted when a work item is fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a change set list ([like the Nuget one](http://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets)) does display short SHA1, any commit link you click on is actually the full SHA1:

http://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/a5557ecdb5b0728945e1ced8e7ae9983d7f3b4bc

So the information about the SHA1 is never lost.